# Not reading the CSS - Express ejs layouts

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I am using the express ejs layouts but only the mainPage can read the css the other pages don't read it (the css, the html read it).

Another question, if I wanted to use another layout (ex: layout2.ejs) what would i do to act on a specific page.

Tree:

Project

- public 

    - js 

    - css 

        - style.css 

- routes 

    - index.js 

    - users.js 

- views

    - layout.ejs

    - mainPage.ejs 

    - login.ejs 

     ...

- app.js

#### I am using particles.js if you need to know.

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const expL = require('express-ejs-layouts');

const app = express(); //Create a Web Application


//EJS
app.use(expL);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

//Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'));
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));


app.listen(3000, ()=> console.log('Listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/',(req, res) => {
    res.render('mainPage',{title: 'Groupy'}); (THIS ONE WORK AND READ THE CSS)
});

module.exports = router;
```

users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//Login Page
router.get('/login',function(req, res) { 
    res.render('login',{title: 'Groupy Login'}); (DON'T READ CSS)
});

//Register Page
router.get('/register',function(req, res) {
    res.render('register',{title: 'Groupy Register'}); (DON'T READ CSS)
});

module.exports = router;
```

layout.ejs

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    </script>

    <title><%= title %></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="particles-js"> </div>
    <script src="js/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <h2>teste</h2>
    <%- body %> 
</body>
```

mainPage.ejs

```
<h1 id="title">Groupy</h1>
    <div id="firstBox">
        <div id="SignIn"><a href="/users/register">Register </a><div id="login"><a href="/users/login">Login</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
   <div id="mainBox"></div>
```

login.ejs

```
<h1 id="title">Groupy Login</h1>
```

Reseult of login (without CSS):

teste

Groupy Login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was the path of css and javascript (particles.js)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"> 

<script src="/js/particles.min.js"></script>   
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following app.use instead of `app.use(express.static('public'))`

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Also you should import path module

```
const path = require('path');
```

Comment: Did you install path module? `npm install path`

Comment: Well didn't had errors so i thought it was already installed, but i installed and still without css. So strange.